# Should I use generic or concrete setters and getters to handle mapping entities?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design, clean-architecture

I have an application where users are able to change some settings. Users can change (set) and read (get) their settings, it's a mapping-like structure.
I made an `UserSettingsInteractor` object that implements the use cases of changing and reading settings, in Python it looks like:

```py
class UserSettingsInteractor:

    def __init__(self, ...): ...

    def set_foo(self, user_id: int, value): ...
    def get_foo(self, user_id: int): ...
    
    def set_bar(self, user_id: int, value): ...
    def get_bar(self, user_id: int): ...

    ...
```

The good point in it is that the existing settings, `foo` and `bar`, are explicit. But writing a setter and getter makes it much verbose. It could be a generalized as:

```py
class UserSettingsInteractor:

    def __init__(self, ...): ...

    def set(self, user_id: int, setting: str, value): ...
    def get(self, user_id: int, setting: str): ...
```

Now the client code knows how a setting is represented, it's a key-value pair. Does not it make the code more fragile?

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the generic approach does not give you much additional benefit:

- It is not better readable - the setting name will just appear as a parameter rather than in the function name. And you will have to implement a long case statement inside the getter/setter instead of distinguishing several functions at class level.
- Same level of coupling - if there were changes in the settings (e.g. quantity or names of the items), you would still have to make changes on both the client and the service side.
- You will not see semantical errors at compile time (I think this is what you mean by "fragile").

The only reason to use the generic approach that I can think of is if for some reason you need a stable interface that is independent of specific settings, for example if you were developing a generic `UserSettings` service that you want to reuse in another application scenario.

Further reading: [Concrete vs Generic – The story of a data model](https://tuhrig.de/concrete-vs-generic-the-story-of-a-data-model/)